# Is there a way to determine what services use  a specific syslog facility on RHEL?

Tags: syslog

I am currently logging all haproxy information to local0 and loca1 facilities (depending on message level).

At the moment, logging gets properly routed to the haproxy logs 'err.log' and 'general.log', but duplicate entries also get placed in /var/log/messages

I want to turn off local0.* and local1.* messages to the /var/log/messages file, but I want to make sure no other service uses these facilities.

Is there a way find out which services use a specific facility on RHEL 5?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don`t see log entries there is no way to potentially know that. There is no syslog-register or something like that.

But to achieve your goal you can fine-tune syslog by:

1. Installing rsyslog
2. Removing the old syslog (and don`t forget to put rsyslog into the runlevels)

The installed rsyslog-configuration file will do exactly the same at the beginning as a default syslog-configuration. BUT: You can fine-tune it - e.g. write messages sent by program X via syslog-facility Y to file Z - next rule: dont`t write these messages anywhere else.